# Loop a query match and remove subset items

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two tables which hold the information on items that have been completed I needed to do it this way for reporting purposes.

```
qry = db.AssemblyListItems
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.ProductionPlanID == (long)_currentPlan.ProductionPlan )
            .ToList();

var _query = qry.Where(w => w.ItemCode == "EPR15CT.L01" && w.DocumentNo == "0000026590")
                .SingleOrDefault();



var hasbeenAssembled = dbCompletedPrinteds
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Where(x => x.ProductionPlanId == (long)_currentPlan.ProductionPlan)
                        .ToList();


foreach (var item in hasbeenAssembled)  {
    qry.RemoveAll(X =>  X.SOPOrderReturnID == Int32.Parse(item.SopLineItemId) );
}
```

If it finds any matching items in the second table to  remove it from the main query.
You will see the tables have much the same data stored in them. But for some reason the the items is still showing in the I need some way of looping the first query with the second query and removing the matching items from the qry object.

[image]

So steps I need to do is :

Loop completed and printed object remove any matching products with the same document number and item code and match the productplan id item and then remove it from the master AssemblyListItems query and then dispaly in a gui at the min its keeping the item in the list.

**Edit 2**

This would work but I dont think its very effiecent.

```
List<AssemblyListItems> _query = qry.ToList();

foreach (AssemblyListItems item in _query)
{

    var hasbeenAssembled = db.CompletedPrinteds.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ProductionPlanId == item.ProductionPlanID).ToList();
    foreach(var subitem in hasbeenAssembled )
    {
        if(item.ProductionPlanID ==subitem.ProductionPlanId && item.DocumentNo == subitem.DocumentNo && item.DocumentNo == subitem.DocumentNo)
        {

            qry.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductionPlanID == subitem.ProductionPlanId && x.DocumentNo == item.DocumentNo && x.ItemCode == subitem.StockCode);


        }


    }

}
```

Edit 3
 To Show the items in the edmx

[image]

Comment: It's quite hard to see exactly what you're asking without a better idea of what these entities are and how they relate.  Could you give a (simplified) view of the tables/entities involved?  I'm guessing it's some sort of 'Master Item' and 'Line item' relationship, and you're trying to only show line items for a particular master item which haven't been printed or something?

Comment: My feeling is you can *probably* simply do this via the initial query by adding a .Contains or something somewhere, but it's hard without a bit more knowledge of what you're working with

Comment: @GPW please see above thanks edit showing the entitys in the process workers complete units at this stage it gets written to the completed and prtinted table FuelAssembledListItems is based on tables from sage in a sql view I simply want to remove items from the first query based on what is in the second query. I have code that works but it doesent seem suffiecent

Answer (score 0):

Last week I did query below using Left outer Join to get three group of data

```
var results = (from srs in srsEmps
               join dest in destEmps on srs.EmpCode equals dest.EmpCode into dsNull
               from dest in dsNull.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new { srs = srs, dest = dest }).ToList();

var Common = results.Where(x => (x.srs != null) && ( x.dest != null)).ToList();
var Deleted = results.Where(x => x.dest != null).ToList();
var NewlyAdded = results.Where(x => x.srs != null);
```

Comment: please see my edit 2 above might give you understand of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
//first get list of assembled/completed items with the _currentplan's ID:
var  hasbeenAssembled = 
    dbCompletedPrinteds
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.ProductionPlanId == (long)_currentPlan.ProductionPlan)
    //note: not sure of underlying DB technology here, but this .ToList() will
    //typically cause a DB query to execute here.
    .ToList();

//next, use that to filter the main query.
qry = db.AssemblyListItems
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => 
        //Get current plan items
        (x.ProductionPlanID == (long)_currentPlan.ProductionPlan)
        //filter out items which are in the previous list of 'completed' ones
        && (!hasBeenAssembled.Any(hba => hba.SopLineItemId==x.SOPOrderReturnID))
    )              
    .ToList();

//I don't have any idea what _query is for, it doesn't seem to be used for anything 
//in this example...
var _query = qry.Where(w => w.ItemCode == "EPR15CT.L01" && w.DocumentNo == "0000026590")
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: _query was just a test so if i could see that it removed a specific item from the list